# Leitura do arquivo Json em Python (iniciante)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, lista, dicionário

Bom dia! Estou começando no python e não estou conseguindo fazer a leitura de dois campos específicos no json gerado, com o seguinte formato:

```js
    [
        {
            "nomeArq": "arquivoA",
            "dataAnt": "28042020",
            "dataAtu": "30042020",
            "qtdAnt": 1500,
            "qtdAtu": 2500,
            "percDif": 66.80
        },
        {
            "nomeArq": "arquivoB",
            "dataAnt": "28042020",
            "dataAtu": "30042020",
            "qtdAnt": 1000,
            "qtdAtu": 1700,
            "percDif": 70.00
        },
        {
            "nomeArq": "arquivoC",
            "dataAnt": "28042020",
            "dataAtu": "30042020",
            "qtdAnt": 2500,
            "qtdAtu": 2125,
            "percDif": -15.00
        }
    ]
```

Na leitura do arquivo, ele interpreta como uma lista, e eu preciso pegar os campos nomeArq e percDif para fazer um gráfico no pyplot. Consigo visualizar o conteúdo no campo em um print, mas não consigo fazer nenhuma movimentação ou dar um append na lista que usarei para gerar o gráfico. Tentei converter para string mas também não funcionou:

```
with open(nomeArquivoJson, 'r') as jsonFileLeitura:
    dadosJson = json.load(jsonFileLeitura)
    print(dadosJson)
    print(dadosJson[0])
    print(dadosJson[0]['nomeArq'])

    for i in dadosJson:
        nomeOrg = str(dadosJson[i]['nomeOrg'])
        print(nomeOrg)

        listaNomeOrg.append(dadosJson[i]['nomeOrg'])
        listaPercVar.append(dadosJson[i]['percDif'])

print(listaNomeOrg)
print(listaPercVar)
```

O retorno, junto com o erro, é:

```
    [{'nomeArq': 'arquivoA', 'dataAnt': '28042020', 'dataAtu': '30042020', 'qtdAnt': 1500, 'qtdAtu': 2500, 'percDif': 66.8}, {'nomeArq': 'arquivoB', 'dataAnt': '28042020', 'dataAtu': '30042020', 'qtdAnt': 1000, 'qtdAtu': 1700, 'percDif': 70.0}, {'nomeArq': 'arquivoC', 'dataAnt': '28042020', 'dataAtu': '30042020', 'qtdAnt': 2500, 'qtdAtu': 2125, 'percDif': -15.0}]
    {'nomeArq': 'arquivoA', 'dataAnt': '28042020', 'dataAtu': '30042020', 'qtdAnt': 1500, 'qtdAtu': 2500, 'percDif': 66.8}
    arquivoA
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/millena/Documentos/poc-monit/poc2GeraGraficov2.py", line 80, in <module>
        geraGrafico()
      File "/home/millena/Documentos/poc-monit/poc2GeraGraficov2.py", line 40, in geraGrafico
        nomeOrg = str(dadosJson[i]['nomeArq'])
    TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

Como faço para fazer a leitura desses dois campos (nomeArq e PercDif) para poder adicioná-los numa lista para fazer o gráfico?

Obrigada!

Comment: Dois erros: Primeiro que o seu JSON não possui a chave [`nomeOrg`]. Segundo, quando faz `dadosJson[i]['percDif']` a variável `i` já é um elemento de `dadosJson` obtido em `for i in dadosJson:` a mensagem de erro está acusando que está tentando usar um objeto complexo com chave no caso um próprio elemento da lista, faça `i['percDif']`.

Comment: Veja esse [exemplo](https://repl.it/@RonaldoVasques/Json01)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode converter a *lista de dicionários* para um *dicionário de listas* filtrando apenas os campos que te interessam, veja só:

```
import json

campos = ['nomeArq','percDif']

with open('teste.json') as f:
    entrada = json.load(f)

saida = {campo:[] for campo in campos}

for elemento in entrada:
    for campo in campos:
        saida[campo].append(elemento[campo])

print(saida)
```

Saída:

```
{'nomeArq': ['arquivoA', 'arquivoB', 'arquivoC'], 'percDif': [66.8, 70.0, -15.0]}
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/DelectableAdmiredFiber)

Resumindo em um *dictionary comprehension* combinado com uma *list comprehension*:

```
import json

campos = ['nomeArq','percDif']

with open('teste.json') as f:
    entrada = json.load(f)

saida = {c: [e[c] for e in entrada] for c in campos}

print(saida)
```

Saída:

```
{'nomeArq': ['arquivoA', 'arquivoB', 'arquivoC'], 'percDif': [66.8, 70.0, -15.0]}
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/LightcoralSimultaneousProfiles)

Geração de gráfico de linhas com o `pyplot`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import json

campos = ['qtdAnt', 'qtdAtu', 'percDif']

with open('teste.json') as f:
    entrada = json.load(f)

saida = {c: [e[c] for e in entrada] for c in campos}

for campo in campos:
    plt.plot(saida[campo], label=campo)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]